# Providing zip/unzip functionalities as a service in Spring/CDI/etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cdi

My application - a Swing-based desktop application (but I think that doesn't matter) - uses Spring Boot (but the question would be the same if I'd use CDI or DI container XYZ). The application is capable of updating itself. Therefore it downloads an update zip file from an HTTP server if available, directly unzipping it in a temporary folder.

I've provided this unzip functionality via an injectable `ZipService` which has currently only one method `void unzip(URL url, Path directory) throws IOException`.
The idea was to provide a simple API and to spare the API client (in my case the API client is just another managed bean) details like "connection timeout" or "read timeout" (both in milliseconds) as this are already provided via app configuration.

How do you handle such use cases where you want to provide some API and do not want to bother the client of the API with details (for example configuration parameters) like in the example above? If there are even some known design patterns helpful in such cases then please let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to achieve modularity. Have you looked into OSGi?

Comment: What you've done is fine IMO. Is there something specific that is troubling you?

Comment: @lane.maxwell Thanks Lane for the tip, but in my case (quite a small application) OSGi would be a bit of a overkill.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Nikos, what is troubling me is basically the question when to use a dedicated service (plus corresponding interface) and when to use just old-school "new SomeLogic(..., someConfigParam...)"especially when application configuration is involved ... I always tend to use services, but with all those additional interfaces and classes and dependencies in the constructor etc. produces quite a lot of code... I struggle a bit what's the right way to do in for example the above mentioned zip use case (and a lot of other quite similar use cases)...